# Two-way routing for router and openvpn server subnets

Tags: routing, router, openvpn, subnet

I have a router with IP 192.168.1.1 subnetting 192.168.1.0/24.

On that subnet, a synology nas has an IP of 192.168.1.181 and is running a VPN server using subnet 192.168.2.0/24.

When I connect a client to that server from outside both networks, I get assigned 192.168.2.6. From that client I can ping machines on 192.168.1.0 (192.168.1.17 for example) and 192.168.1.1 & 192.168.2.1.

From machines already on 192.168.1.0, I cannot ping the VPN clients.

I would like to have two-way access across both subnets. What do I need to do?

Comment: Add a route to 192.168.2.0/24 via the Synology NAS (192.168.1.181).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your clients need a route to 192.168.2.0/24 (the network being used by your vpn clients).  The easiest way to do this is to ensure that the default gateway for your network (192.168.1.1) knows you to reach that network, possibly by setting up a static route to 192.168.2.0/24 via your OpenVPN server.  How to do this depends on your router; on Linux, that would look something like:

```
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.181
```

Alternatively, you can give each of your clients a static route to this network.

You will also need to ensure that our OpenVPN server is configured to route traffic between these networks (e.g., making sure that your firewall is configured to permit forwarded traffic from your 192.168.1.0/24 network to the VPN network).

Comment: Tried `route add 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.181` and got: 
`C:\WINDOWS\system32\ROUTE.EXE: bad argument 192.168.1.181` | Also I have this exact route in my 192.168.1.1 router.

Comment: I have no idea what the appropriate Windows command line would look like.  I would start with `route /?` and Google, I guess.

Comment: I was using https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc757323%28v=WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Oops didn't specify arguments

Comment: If you already have the appropriate route in your router, it may be time for some diagnostics with something like `tcpdump` to figure out if traffic from your local systems is actually reaching the OpenVPN server or not.

Comment: Ok I can ping the vpn client at .2.6 from .1.17 now.

Comment: Have you looked at the second part of the answer? If you've already got the network route set up, it's likely that you don't have OpenVPN configured to allow routing back to the connected client. This doesn't just have to do with firewall settings, it also has to do with enabling the client-to-client option in the OpenVPN configuration.

Comment: I'm using whatever the default Synology OpenVPN configs are + checking a box that supposedly "Allow[s] clients to access servers LAN"

Comment: I'm not certain that you're going to be able to achieve your desired state by using the options available in the Synology GUI. It looks like many of the options that are available when you configure OpenVPN through the use of config files are simply not available in Synology.